# Append data in a storage array in huff

Tags: arrays, huff

How would one append data to a storage array in huff?

Let's say for example we start off with an array that looks like:

```
[0]
```

And want to end with an array that looks like:

```
[0,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store a dynamic array, you first have to get a starting storage slot.

Let's say our starting storage slot is n.

Then to get the storage slot for the first value, you just have to hash n like this:

```js
keccak256(n);
```

This will give you the storage slot where to save the first variable.

Then if you want to push something to the array, you compute the hash again and add 1:

```js
keccak256(n) + 1;
```

And so on.

So in huff it will look something like this:

```js
#define macro STORE_BYTES32() = takes(0) returns(0) {
    0x04 calldataload    // [Argument to store]
    [STARTING_SLOT]      // [StartingSLot, Argument]
    0x00 mstore          // [Argument]
    0x20 0x00            // [offset, size, Argument]
    sha3                 // [HashedStorageSlot, Argument]
    sstore               // []
}
```

This stores the first value. To store the second value after the sha3, just add 1 to it.

Also, in solidity, the first storage slot n holds the size of the array.

That's how the EVM knows where to push the next variable.

I created a contract that shows how to do dynamic arrays: https://github.com/Kuly14/Huff-Arrays/blob/main/src/DynamicArray.huff

It is a bit more complex than the example above because we need to calculate how many items are in the array to not override any vars.

I didn't yet have time to create any tests for it so just keep that in mind.

It gets a lot more complicated if you want to pack the variables together into the same slot to save gas. You have to do a lot of bytes masking.

Here is a great article by noxx on the topic: https://noxx.substack.com/p/evm-deep-dives-the-path-to-shadowy-3ea

Here is also link to the docs where it's explained more in depth: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/internals/layout_in_storage.html#bytes-and-string

Comment: This is great! I'd love to see some examples of a solidity style dynamic array, a vyper style bounded dynamic array, and a full fixed array... But that'll probably take some time and some tests. This solves the answer for now, thanks!